# How can I change the colour of my window background randomly in java?

Tags: java, swing, random, colors

I am working on this program just for fun and had this idea of implemented a random background colour changer. Doing research and through my knowledge I have managed to come across a 1 line code which does that as I require. But I am having trouble understand the full code. Could someone explain it to me please, I will really appreciate it... The code is below.

```
new Color((int) (Math.random() * 0x1000000))
```

What I believe this code is doing is that creates a new instance of the method colour already created by java, converts that into an integer and gets a random number from that and times that by 0x1000000. Is this correct, please correct me.

I am finding it difficult to understand why does it times by 0x10000000, would that end up back to 0. Thanks, I really appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: `0x1000000 = 16777216` (16 millions colors), see http://davidnaylor.org/blog/2005/02/all-16777216-rgb-colours/ for example

Comment: What do you mean, 0x1000000 means 16 million colours, wouldnt 0*1000000 = to 0. Could you confirm whether i explained the math.random properly as well, thanks.

Comment: It's the prefix 0x. It's not an arithmetic expression meaning "multiply", it's short for "hexadecimal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems really dull to me. Because `Math.random()` returns a decimal number, multiplying it by 0x1000000 will multiply it by whatever 1,000,000 is in hexadecimal format.

The code I would use is:

`Color c = new Color(new Random().nextInt(256), new Random().nextInt(256), new Random().nextInt(256));`

or

`Color c = new Color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());`

The former would generate random integers up to 255 (inclusive) and put them as R, G and B parameters for a Color constructor, whereas, the latter would generate random decimals (sort of like percentages) as percentages for the R, G and B parameters for a Color constructor.

Test it out and report what you find! :)

Jarod.

Comment: @mastercort889, hi, it is giving me an error on both of the code your gave.

Comment: Have you added all the appropriate imports? (Assuming Eclipse IDE)

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` returns a double between 0.0 and 1.0, exclusive on the 1.0 side.  Multiplying times 0x1000000 yields an int value between 0 and 0xffffff.  Which fits a random color.

IMO using `Random.nextInt(0xffffff)` would be clearer.  (Underneath it is doing the same thing)

Answer (score 2):

0x1000000 is not an arithmetic expression, it's hexadecimal value for 16777216.

Math.random returns a random value between 0 and 1, which you then can multiply with the range you're looking for; in your case a full integer.

That integer is then used as argument to a Color-instance which will extract 3 bytes; red, green, and blue m, creating a very random color. As requested.

Alternatively, you could create each color-component individually, making more sense, perhaps, using something like;

```
color = new Color(
    Math.random() * 255, //red
    Math.random() * 255,  //green
    Math.random() * 255); //blue
```